# Android Lint. Is it possible to scan .java classes via command line

Tags: java, android, lint

I am wondering if it is possible to scan `.java` classes via the command line using Android Lint?

My goal is to find all calls of `NewApi` in my Java code.
I am using the following Lint construction:

```
lint ./src --xml "reports/lint.xml"
```

and the result is:

> Lint found 0 errors and 0 warnings

But I know that these calls exist in my project.

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Minor edits for readability and grammar. :)

Answer (score 0):

`Usage: lint [flags] <project directories>`

Lint does that false "no problem" thing if it can't find a project. Instead of passing in `./src`, use just `.`. This should be where the AndroidManifest.xml file is in Ant/Eclipse-build projects. For newer gradle projects you have to run `gradle lint` anyway. So your command line ought to be:

```
lint . --xml "reports/lint.xml"
```